# Como remover um "href" de uma tag <a> com JQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho uma tag `<a>` com hiperlink devidamente setado. Porém, gostaria de removê-la ao disparar de um evento. A mesma tag tem um ID devidamente setado, também (único, válido, e afins).

Gostaria de saber se existe uma função para remover o atributo `href` e assim tornar o link inválido, ou se existe uma forma de apenas desativar esse link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**A solução moderna para desativar um link é somente CSS:** ([para Browsers modernos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events))

```
$('#minhaID').css("pointer-events", "none");

// e para re-activar basta usar:
$('#minhaID').css("pointer-events", "");
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn52U/1)

Pode usar tambem assim:

```
$('#minhaID').attr("href", "");
```

Ou ainda:

```
$('#minhaID').removeAttr('href'); // note que esta opcção remove algumas caracteristicas importantes do elemento como focus.
```

dependendo da utilização que quiser dar.

Nota: O Chrome tem uma discussão aberta sobre a possibilidade de deixar de suportar pointer-events.

Comment: Solução interessante, também. Parabéns!

Comment: sabe me dizer se é possível reverter esse processo e se sim, como?

Comment: @DennisBraga, sim, é fácil, basta usar `$('#minhaID').css("pointer-events", "");` - Exemplo: __http://jsfiddle.net/Tn52U/1/__

Comment: Edita a tua resposta e adiciona isso. É muito legal isso de poder retirar o link sem perder informação e poder, simplesmente via CSS, reativar. :D

Comment: @DennisBraga, feito! boa ideia.

Comment: Essa solução em css é suportada por navegadores antigos?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo não. Juntei um link para dar essa informação.

Comment: Só tomem cuidado ao usar o pointer-events, pois ele só funciona em 3 navegadores... conforme a especificação: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer%20events

Answer (score 11):

Seria apenas isso?

```
$('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: Teoricamente, sim... mas não funfou comigo! Pensei que estivesse fazendo errado, ou coisa do tipo. Estou chamando pelo ID do link, mas acho que esse não é ponto.

Comment: UPDATE: Funcionou. Era exatamente isso, mas outra parte do meu código tava atrapalhando isso de funcionar corretamente. Me sinto até meio tapado por ter perguntado isso agora! ¬¬'

Comment: Faz parte, acontece ^^

Answer (score 7):

Existem várias maneiras, pelo javascript puro o ideal é que você use a referencia do seu elemento e nele use o método `removeAttribute`, exemplos:

```
document.querySelector('#minhaAncora').removeAttribute('href');
document.getElementById('minhaAncora').removeAttribute('href');
```

Porém quando você remove essa propriedade da ancora, essa ancora deixa de funcionar como ancora, perdendo as características dos pseudo seletores `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` e `:visited` o que pode ser um comportamento indesejado.

Neste caso você pode substituir o valor do atributo por uma hash, exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('#minhaAncora').setAttribute('href', '#');
```

Porém isso pode influenciar o scroll do navegador dependendo dos elementos e tamanho da página, então uma outra solução é colocar no lugar um script que não faz nada, exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('#minhaAncora').setAttribute('href', 'javascript: ');
```

Ele vai manter as propriedades da ancora mas não irá fazer nada ao ser clicado. Pois o browser interpreta isso como uma "evaluação" de código durante o evento de click, porém como não há código, ele ignora o comando.

Dica para quem usa o jQuery ficaria assim:

```
$('#minhaAncora').attr('href', 'javascript: '); // modifica pra não fazer nada
$('#minhaAncora').attr('href', '#'); // faz o scroll mover-se para inicio do documento, mas não muda de página
$('#minhaAncora').removeAttr('href'); // remove o atributo da tag
```

Caso você não queira remover, pode usar o `pointer-event` do CSS para invalidar o uso de eventos de cursor na tag, porém isso não remove o link que ainda pode ser acessível com focus (use tab) em seguida enter, apenas browsers modernos tem suporte.

Caso você não queira remover o atributo, mas apenas remover o evento deles, é possível prevenir a ação padrão com seguinte código:

```
document.querySelector('#minhaAncora').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Compatível com todos browsers modernos, IE antigos precisa retornar false
// e a forma de adicionar eventos é por outro método.
// No caso use o jQuery:
$('#minhaAncora').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Resposta bem sólida, também. Bom trabalho.

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro, além de remover o atributo, adicionar um estilo para ficar visível ao usuário:

```js
$('#link').removeAttr('href').css({
    'cursor': 'not-allowed',
    'color': '#AAAAAA',
    'text-decoration': 'line-through'
});
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tF5Pm/).

Answer (score 5):

Utilizando javascript puro:

```
document.getElementById('id').removeAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 4):

Se for o seu caso, você também pode cancelar o evento padrão de redirecionamento da âncora com o próprio evento:

```
$('a[href]').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Porque não editar a sua resposta e adicionar esse conteúdo ao invés de criar outra resposta?

Comment: Desta forma quando a âncora for clicada (se for o seu caso) ela não vai redirecionar para a referência.

Comment: Essa função é bem mais interessante, assim não perco a informação do meu link.